# SQLite syntax error near "WHERE" while checking the type

Tags: sqlite, where-clause

I'm new at SQLite and i'm trying to add a column into a table which is exist or not exist with the statement below.

```
ALTER TABLE
  table1
ADD
  columnx TEXT NULL
WHERE
  type = "table"
```

i've got the `SQLiteException: near "WHERE": syntax error (code 1)` error. What is wrong with that statement? What is the correct way of adding new column into a table with checking the existance of the table?

Comment: You can't use a WHERE clause in ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: Alter table syntax is described at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html ; you can't just make up your own.